# Wrong tableview row height on iOS8

Tags: ios, uitableview, ios8, ios9

I have tableview with UITableViewAutomaticDimension rowHeight. One of the cells contain uiview with fixed height.

Inside of that view placed two buttons, and in LayoutSubviews method of that view i use code

```
self.button1.layer.cornerRadius = self.button1.frame.size.height / 2
```

to round that button.

In iOS9 the button is rendered correctly:

[image]

But, on iOS8 the button not render correctly:

[image]

What is the problem? How must i set constraints to make button render correctly in iOS8?

Here the .Xib file of cell:

[Cell xib file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/2iki2psdpex8bfa/TwoButtonsTableViewCell.xib?dl=0)

Comment: Where do you put the cornerRadius setting code? I suggest you to put it in `layoutSubviews`

Comment: you should set corner radius in view will appear method  and before it call layoutIfNeeded

Comment: what is the height of button ?

Comment: try to use any integer value in place of "self.button1.frame.size.height / 2"

Comment: try with setting ClipToBounds = true. may solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

add this line to your custom cell class

```
-(void)layoutSubviews
    {
        [super layoutSubviews];

        self. button1.layer.cornerRadius = self. button1.frame.size. height / 2;
        self. button1.clipsToBounds = YES;
        [self.contentView layoutIfNeeded];
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It works for me. Please try it.

```
self.button1.layer.cornerRadius = self.button1.frame.size.height / 2
self.button1.clipsToBounds = true
```

Hope it will helps you.Thanks